# How to initiate a JTable in a Swing GUI?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to populate a JTable in a GUI and am having a hard time doing it. I know I am missing something simple but I can't figure out what. I have created my own abstractTableModel and I set the GUI Jtable to the model..but it doesn't work....Here is my code:

```
//Here I Try to start and populate the JTable
myTableModel tModel = new myTableModel(a)
transTable.setModel(tModel);
```

And here is the Model I made:

```
package edu.byu.isys.rmyers4.gui;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;


public class myTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

Account a = null;

public myTableModel (Account c){

    this.a = c;

}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return a.getTransactions().size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
   if(col == 0)
   {
       if(a.getTransactions().get(row).isDebit())
       return "Deposit";
   }
   else
   {
       return "Withdrawal";
   }
   if(col == 1){
       return a.getTransactions().get(row).getAmount();

   }
   else if(col == 2){
       return a.getTransactions().get(row).getMemo();

   }
   else if(col == 3){
       return a.getTransactions().get(row).getDate();

   }

   else{
       return null;
   }
}
```

}

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Does the data not show up? Do you get an exception? You have to give us more context.

Comment: @unholysampler Ya the data does not show up. Everything works ok, no errors and everything else is working...just no data in the table, even though there is data in objects that it should be getting the data from.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are not adding the JTable to the screen properly? You can try a simple test:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setContentPane(transTable);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

If indeed `getTransactions()` return rows - you will be able to see them (without column headers as they are not defined in your code).

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the following:

```
if(col == 0)
{
    if(a.getTransactions().get(row).isDebit())
    return "Deposit";
}
else
{
    return "Withdrawal";
}
if(col == 1){
```

should be:

```
if(col == 0)
{
    if(a.getTransactions().get(row).isDebit())
    {
        return "Deposit";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Withdrawal";
    }
}
if(col == 1){
```

Comment: Oh ya that is a problem thanks. Unfortunetly that doesn't really help me with my main problem, that is no data showing up on the table

Answer (score 0):

Since you said camickr's answer does not fix the issue you were actually asking about, the only thing I can think of is that `getTransactions()` is returning an empty list. Therefore, there are no rows (data) to display in the table.